# Console Won't Output or Display at All in Visual Studio on Macbook Pro

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2019

I am just starting to learn C#, and I downloaded Visual Studio as my IDE for Macbook Pro, however when I try to run my HelloWorld program, I receive the following error message:

"Debugger operation failed

ScriptError: Terminal got an error: AppleEvent timed out."

Unfortunately, I get no output from the console, in fact the console window does not even appear. I would appreciate any help you can give me. Below I have included a screenshot of the error as well. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers given if you google that error?

Comment: I googled the error and what I found was the same question posted on a visual studio forum that has been left unresolved for a year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The issue was resolved, my system required a software update.